# Python Out of Index Error

Tags: python, datetime, twitter

I'm working on converting a Twitter created_at date into an integer and using the following code, but i'm getting an out of index error:

```
creation_date = [time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.strptime(status['created_at']
                  ,'%a %b  %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')) for status in statuses]

for x in range(len(creation_date)):
    year = int(creation_date[x][0:4])
    month = int(creation_date[x][5:7])
    day = int(creation_date[x][8:10])
    newCreationDate = []
    newCreationDate[x] = datetime(year,month,day)
```

Comment: Take `newCreationDate = []` out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're emptying the `newCreationDate` array each time through the loop.

```
newCreationDate = []
for d in creation_date:
    year = int(d[0:4])
    month = int(d[5:7])
    day = int(d[8:10])
    newCreationDate.append(datetime(year,month,day))
```

Comment: Won't this give an index error anyway? Trying to access `newCreationDate[0]` in the first iteration of the loop will fail, since the array has no elements.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. Python isn't one of my main languages, other scripting languages allow you to create elements with assignments.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
newCreationDate = []
for x in range(len(creation_date)):
    year = int(creation_date[x][0:4])
    month = int(creation_date[x][5:7])
    day = int(creation_date[x][8:10])
    newCreationDate.append(datetime(year,month,day))
```